# R counting across columns and group_by the first column

Tags: r

I have a data file which looks like the following:

```r
Country Medicine1 Medicine2 Medicine3 Medicine4
CountryA Aspirin  Nyquil    Geritol
CountryA Aspirin  Geritol
CountryA Nyquil   Aspirin   Tylenol   Viagra
CountryB Tylenol  Nyquil    Viagra
CountryB Aspirin  Tylenol
...
CountryZ Fungisil Loprox    Tylenol
CountryZ Aspirin  Geritol   Loprox    Tylenol
```

What I would like to do is to get an output that would count for each country, the sum of the individual drug names across the columns. Such as:

```r
Country Aspirin Fungisil Geritol Loprox Nyquil Tylenol Viagra
CountryA     3        0       2      0      2       1      1
CountryB     1        0       0      0      1       2      1
...
CountryZ     1        1       1      2      0       2      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one potential solution using [tidyverse functions](https://www.tidyverse.org/):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "Country Medicine1 Medicine2 Medicine3 Medicine4
CountryA Aspirin Nyquil Geritol
CountryA Aspirin Geritol
CountryA Nyquil Aspirin Tylenol Viagra
CountryB Tylenol Nyquil Viagra
CountryB Aspirin Tylenol
CountryZ Fungisil Loprox Tylenol
CountryZ Aspirin Geritol Loprox Tylenol", header = TRUE, fill = NA)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Country) %>%
  filter(value != "") %>%
  arrange(value) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Country, names_from = value,
              values_from = name, values_fn = length,
              values_fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 8
#>   Country  Aspirin Fungisil Geritol Loprox Nyquil Tylenol Viagra
#>   <chr>      <int>    <int>   <int>  <int>  <int>   <int>  <int>
#> 1 CountryA       3        0       2      0      2       1      1
#> 2 CountryB       1        0       0      0      1       2      1
#> 3 CountryZ       1        1       1      2      0       2      0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Outstanding!!!! I want to plot this data in a stacked bar-plot. But melt(df, id=c("Country")) isn't working. I get the following error:

"Using Country as id variables
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names"

What I need is:
Country  Variable Value
CountryA Aspirin  3
CountryA Fungisil  0
CountryA Geritol  2
CountryA Loprox   0
CountryA Nyquil   2
CountryA Tylenol  1
CountryA Viagra  1
:::::::
CountryZ Aspirin  1
CountryZ Fungisil  1
CountryZ Geritol  1
CountryZ Loprox   2
CountryZ Nyquil   0
CountryZ Tylenol  2
CountryZ Viagra  0

Comment: If you're having issues with `melt()`, try `pivot_longer()` from the tidyr package. In order to give yourself the best chance of getting help on this forum, my suggestion is to post another question clearly describing what you want the final plot to look like and what you've tried so far.